# Microsoft Index is reducing speed despite backoff being disabled

Tags: windows-10, search-indexing

I am continually receiving the message in the indexer: `Indexing speed is reduced due to user activity`.

I currently have the policy,  `Local Computer Policy\Administrative Template\Windows\Components\Search\Disable Indexer Backoff` enabled.

Also, I have set the value of `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager\DisableBackOffOnUser` to `1`.

Additionally, I set `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager\DisableBackOff` to `1`.

However, the indexer continues to backoff. Am I missing a setting somewhere.

I am running Windows 10 22H2 and have rebooted the system since the above policy was enabled.

---

### Other things I have done that do not work

In addition to want I tried above, I have also added the following DWORD/values:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager\DisableBackOffOnIO`=`1`

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager\DisableBackOffOnCPU`=`1`

---

### Compared to another computer

I looked at the registry for a different Windows 10 machine and there were a lot of entries that don't exist on the computer that is problematic. **Might this be the problem?**

Other Computer Registry
[image]

Problem Computer Registry
[image]

---

**Still, I continue to received the message `indexing speed is reduced due to user activity**

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Same here. I noticed that if I set my power mode from the battery icon to 'best', it keeps going unless there is a lot of activity. If I switch to 'best battery life' it stops(pauses). So somehow it takes the power profile into account. Very annoying.